# GulpJS: Perform string functions on SVG file contents

Tags: javascript, svg, replace, gulp, adobe-illustrator

I have an illustrator file I'm regularly updating, that's then processed and distributed to /public/ though a Gulp task.

However, Illustrator appends `_[0-9]+_` to some key tag IDs, and I want to perform something like `.pipe(thisSVGFile.contents().replace('/_[0-9]+_/',""))` whenever Gulp Watch comes across a change.

How can I achieve this without producing my own Gulp plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[gulp-replace](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-replace)** supports regular expressions.

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('replace', function () {
  return gulp.src('./public/file.svg')
    .pipe(replace(/_[0-9]+_/g, ''))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

Comment: Hrmm, I suppose this works, just another thing to add to my ever-growing list of requires... cheers :)

Comment: Glad to have helped ! Take a look to [this plugin](https://github.com/jackfranklin/gulp-load-plugins) :)